# Need to find '$word;' pattern in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have big text file and I have to find all words starts with '$' and ends with ';' like `$word;`.

```
import re

text = "$h;BREWERY$h_end;You've built yourself a brewery."
x = re.findall("$..;", text)
print(x)
```

I want my output like `['$h;', '$h_end;']` How can I do that?

Comment: `x = re.findall("\$[a-zA-Z_]+;", text)`

Comment: try this `"\$.*?;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have to find all words starts with '$' and ends with ';' like $word;.*

I would do:

```
import re
text = "$h;BREWERY$h_end;You've built yourself a brewery."
result = re.findall('\$[^;]+;',text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['$h;', '$h_end;']
```

Note that `$` needs to be escaped (`\$`) as it is one of [special characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Then I match 1 or more occurences of anything but `;` and finally `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\$\w+;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5tlhSh/1). Details:

- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\w+` - 1+ letters, digits, `_` (=*word*) chars
- `;` - a semi-colon.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Oo7GD7):

```
import re

text = "$h;BREWERY$h_end;You've built yourself a brewery."
x = re.findall(r"\$\w+;", text)
print(x) # => ['$h;', '$h_end;']
```